# Create Index in RavenDB

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

I have the following document :

```
public class Cars
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //collection of car price id
    public List<string> CarsPriceIds { get; set; }
}
public class CarsPriceIds 
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> CarTypesIds { get; set; }
}

public class CarTypes
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

 }
```

My input is Car.
I need to display in my view
the car name and the CarType.Name match to CarsPriceIds

I start write my index and got stuck. Here is my index

```
new IndexDefinitionBuilder<Cars>
{
  Map = docs => from doc in docs
  from carsPriceId in doc.CarsPriceIds 
  from carTypes in ????
  select new { doc.Name}
}
```

I can't continue!!!
What next??
Any help please

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have probably chosen the wrong model, because it seems that CarPrice and CarType have no meaning outside Car. Therefore they should be *inside* the Car document. Generally your documents are equal to your aggregate roots in DDD terms.

However, if you really want to stick with this model and just want an index that can join your CarPrices and CarTypes, take a look at this: http://ayende.com/blog/4661/ravendb-live-projections-or-how-to-do-joins-in-a-non-relational-database

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at live projections:

http://ayende.com/blog/4661/ravendb-live-projections-or-how-to-do-joins-in-a-non-relational-database